# Where to restore my fragment’s state in this case?

Tags: android, android-fragments, savestate

Beginner here. I have an Activity that holds a ViewPager that, in turn, has 3 fragments:

```
[ Activity ]
    [ ViewPager ]
        [ Frag1 ]
        [ Frag2 ]
        [ Frag3 ]
```

Say I’m in Frag3 and I’ve done some work in it, and my app has assigned a value to one of the member variables in that fragment.

I then tap Home (my Activity goes to the background and it’s onStop method is called). Then I tap Recents on my phone and choose my Activity again (it comes back to the foreground and it shows my Frag3).

The value being held by that member variable in my Fragment has been lost.

I’ve saved that value in the onSaveInstanceState method in my Fragment, but I don’t know when I should retrieve it. I’ve read I’m supposed to do that in onActivityCreated, but in the case I just described, it won’t be called (I believe only onStart and onResume will be called, right? OnActivityCreated is only called if I swipe all the way to Frag1 and then back to Frag3) and my app will crash (it has).

When should I retrieve the values in the Bundle in this case?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Fragments, the counterpart is onCreateView. There you have third parameter which is named `savedInstanceState`.

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle))

> savedInstanceState    (Bundle): If non-null, this fragment is being re-constructed from a previous saved state as given here.

Comment: onCreateView comes before onActivityCreated, so it's not called either, I've just tried it... thanks for the help, though!

Comment: hmm. when are you setting the adapter for ViewPager?

Comment: in my Activity's onCreate method.